# Liferay Friendly URL struts action not fired

Tags: liferay

Please help me to implement Friendly URL

**My source URL**
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/myshop? p_p_id=225_INSTANCE_08MX& p_p_lifecycle=0 &p_p_state=normal& p_p_mode=view& p_p_col_id=column-1&
 p_p_col_count=1 &_225_INSTANCE_08MX_struts_action=%2Fproduct%2Fview_product
 &_225_INSTANCE_08MX_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fweb%2Fguest%2Fprodu­ct%3Fp_p_id%3D25_INSTANCE_08MX%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mo­de%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1%26_225_INSTANCE_08MX_%252F­%3D&_225_INSTANCE_08MX_productId=25414

Please can some one help me to write route file.

Thanks
Tania

Comment: What did you already try? Does it work? Have you searched for "liferay friendly url" and don't understand the available documentation and examples? Or do you just want us to provide the deployable code for you?

Comment: First thanks for trying to help. This is my route file

Comment: <routes> 
<route> 
<pattern></pattern> 
<ignored-parameter name="redirect" />
<implicit-parameter name="p_p_id">225_INSTANCE_08MX</implicit-parameter>
<implicit-parameter name="struts_action">/product/view</implicit-parameter> 
</route> 
<route> 
<pattern>/{productId:\d+}/view</pattern> 
<ignored-parameter name="redirect" />
<implicit-parameter name="p_p_id">225_INSTANCE_08MX</implicit-parameter>
<implicit-parameter name="p_p_state">maximized</implicit-parameter>
<implicit-parameter name="struts_action">/product/view_product</implicit-parameter> </route> 
</routes>

Comment: The generated friendly url is 
http://localhost:8080/web/guest/myshop/-/product/15414/view The problem is this friendly url is put in an Href link and when I click on it it doesn't fire struts_action view_product.It simply stays in the same page.

Comment: I'm stuck up with this for several days and I really need your help. Thanks alot. Tania

Comment: To get better help, please edit your question and add the (well formatted) xml code and other information to it. Who's supposed to read this blob in a comment? If you really need that help, please do your homework and make the question as information dense and readable. It's really hard to decipher what you're doing